# Can flatbuffers parse json given a generated type?

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

After using `flatc` to generate a type, can I parse a string of JSON into this type?

In [documentation](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_cpp.html), we can see

> This works similarly to how the command-line compiler works: a sequence of files parsed by the same Parser object allow later files to reference definitions in earlier files. Typically this means you first load a schema file (which populates Parser with definitions), followed by one or more JSON files.

And there is [sample code](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/samples/sample_text.cpp) in `sample_text.cpp`

```
ok = parser.Parse(schemafile.c_str(), include_directories) &&
     parser.Parse(jsonfile.c_str(), include_directories);
```

However, this means I must distribute the original `.fbs` schema file together with my application. Since I have already generate the C++ type using `flatc` during build time, can I parse a JSON string into this type without having to parse the schema one more time during runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you currently can't. There's no JSON parsing code in the generated code.

Parsing the schema is really quick though, and you can reuse the `Parser` object that has parsed the schema for multiple JSON files.